# Angularjs - Directive Two-way binding Isolated Scope Issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building a SPA based on AngularJS. In one component of the SPA I have a document upload system, which is built via a custom directive below called docmgmt. Within the component docmgmt I have an another custom directive component called modalCompanyQuery. It is a modal window that searches the company database and returns matching company results. Upon the finding the right company the user clicks on the company name which is then passed back to the parent directive docmgmt called modalOutput.

The issue I have is that despite using two way binding '=' a new scope for modalOutput (output) is created in modalCompanyQuery. How can I pass the modalCompanyQuery search result (modalOutput) back to the parent directive docmgmt? Any help on the simplest way to return the results would be great. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code simplified

**modalCompanyQuery Template**

```
<div modal-company-query dialog-show="modalCompanyQuery.isShow"  dialog-name ="Select Company" dialog-class="modalSelectCompany" dialog-icon ="fa fa-building" dialog-header="modalSelectCompany-header" company-type = "srchCompanyTypeList" output-select="modalOutput">
</div>
```

**Directive docmgmt**

```
angular.module("docmgmt", [])
.directive("docmgmt",['$http','sessionService','Upload','docService', function($http,sessionService,Upload,docService){


    return{
                link: function(scope,element,attrs){ 
                   scope.docRecord = {};
                   scope.rightPane = {showAction:true, showInsert:false,showUpdate:false, showRead:false};   
                   scope.progressBar = 0;
                   scope.submit =[{}];

                //modal company search and linking search output results to docmgmt scope

                   scope.modalCompanyQuery = {isShow:false};
                   scope.modalOutput={};
                   scope.test=function(){
                        console.log(scope.modalOutput);
                    }



                },//return
                restrict:"A", 
                replace:true,


                templateUrl:"partials/docmgmt/docmgmt.html",//template
                transclude:true,
                scope:{
                } 
            }//return
}]);
```

**Directive modalCompanyQuery**

```
 angular.module("company", [])
    .directive("modalCompanyQuery",['$http','companyService', function($http,companyService){

    return{
                link: function(scope,element,attrs){ // normal variables rather than actual $scope, that is the scope data is passed into scope



                   //Read Company
                   scope.getRecord = function(result){
                     scope.output={id:result.cs_id, type:result.type,name:result.name, active: result.active};
                     console.log(scope.output);
                     scope.isShow = false;
                   }//getRecord

                   /*AJAX search functions go here*/

                },//return
                restrict:"A", //assign as attribute only ie <div my-modal> Content </div>
                replace:true,//replaces div with element, note if this is the case must all template must be wrapped within one root element. eg button is within ul otherwise get an error. 


                templateUrl:"partials/company/tpl/desktop/modal-company-query-desktop.html",//template
                transclude:true, //incorporate additional data within
                scope:{
                    isShow:"=dialogShow",//two way binding
                    name:"@dialogName",//name to be in header
                    dialogClass:"@dialogClass",// style of the dialog
                    dialogHeader:"@dialogHeader",//color of the dialogHeader 
                    dialogIcon:"@dialogIcon",//font awesome icon
                    output:"=outputSelect"
                    //selectCompany:"=selectCompany",//company to be selected from search and passed back to main window
                } //If on this should mean the html input is not binded to custom directive
            }//return
}]);
```

Comment: whenever you do `scope: {}`, the directive forgets all the parent scopes and it refers only what is passed in this. `=` is to pass an **javascript Object** in the directive scope and `@` is to pass string. Both are 2-way binding I think.

Comment: And if `outputSelect` is part of your parent controller scope, you can set the `output` in directive and this should work.

Comment: The outputSelect is part of the parent scope which is modalOutput. But the values are not passing from modalCompanyQuery back to docmgmt. I would like to know how to pass it back to the parent.

Comment: what is the type of `outputSelect` is the parent scope?

Comment: see the the code **modalCompanyQuery Template** and **Directive docmgmt** output-select is  scope.modalOutput={};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the solution. The following two links really helped me understand the problem and solution.

[Understanding $emit, $broadcast and $on in AngularJS](https://web.archive.org/web/20160904175426/http://www.dotnet-tricks.com:80/Tutorial/angularjs/HM0L291214-Understanding-$emit,-$broadcast-and-$on-in-AngularJS.html)

[Communication between nested directives](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223006/communication-between-nested-directives)

So I end up using $emit and $on. Outcome as follows:

**Directive modalCompanyQuery**

```
             scope.getRecord = function(result){
               scope.output={id:result.cs_id, type:result.type,name:result.name, active: result.active};
               scope.$emit('companyRecord', {record:scope.output});
               scope.isShow = false;
             }//getRecord
```

**Directive docmgmt**

```
            scope.$on('companyRecord', function (event, args) {
             scope.modalOutput = args.record;
             console.log('Success');
             console.log(scope.modalOutput);
            });
```

Hope this helps other people that have come across the same brickwall!

Answer (score 0):

alright, in your `docmgmt` directive, I see you have made the scope of the directive empty doing:
 **`scope: {}`**.

I think you should do it like:

```
scope: {
     modalOutput: "="
}
```

> btw doing above expects an **attribute** in your directive template with name `modal-output` which must be an `object` type.

Try it...

Comment: Thanks for your help but it didnt work. I think it is to do with isolated scope and nested directives. Any way I found a solution using $emit and $on see below. Thanks again for giving it a go!